# Identifying methods that can be converted into a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I've been searching around to practice my recursion, however I've run out of practice problems on codingBat, and a few others. If you've got more suggestions, feel free to comment them!

My question is **how do YOU identify when a method can simply be turned into a recursive method, even if you have to or can change the parameters?**

Elements of a recursion method of that are needed would be a needed *base case* which deems the end of the recursion, as well as a *reason to loop or not loop (which reverts to base case condition)*. Am I perhaps missing any other important aspects of recursive methods?

An example of a recursive method I've found (but not yet solved to be recursed) is below. It is from codingBat, and I am not asking anyone to correct my code. It is simply an example of a method that can be converted, that I've found. I'll figure it out.

Editing as answers come in. Removed example due to confusion.
Requirements to watch for when writing a recursive method:

1. StackOverFlow error.
2. All methods that contain a loop can be recursed, however it may not be the best choice of implementation.
3. A recursive method should be *natural* to the problem being solved.

Comment: Even in your example recursive method is less efficient than a plain method based on StringBuilder. You should use recursion only when it's a natural way to solve a problem, not because you just can use it.

Comment: Every method can be converted in a recursive one. Some languages like *Haskell* and *Prolog* have no other mechanism to loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, recursion can simulate every loop, so you *could* create a recursive method for just about every method containing a loop – *however* it is not guaranteed that the recursive version will finish (because your looped version may use state to cache results, while your recursive version doesn't) or even run (because you may get a `StackOverflowError` – how fitting).

Edit: Note that even if using direct recursion may lead to stack overflow, there is a technique to work around even that problem, namely [trampolining](http://jtauber.com/blog/2008/03/30/thunks,_trampolines_and_continuation_passing/) (article is for python, but also works with Java 8's lambdas).

Edit 2: Please also note that the relation between iterative and recursive solutions is due to the [Church-Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis)-conjecture.

Comment: state is usually required to model or cache results that could be computed by recursion - every loop is convertible to recursion form

Comment: This is essentially what I'm looking for, along with intuitively knowing that some methods that cannot be recused shouldn't due to the Stackoverflow.

Comment: @JacobHein, if this answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to go about selecting an answer for now. All answers say the same thing with different additions. I will wait a short bit to see what comments/upvotes say and choose the answer from there.

Answer (score 1):

turning a loop to a recursion is always possible (not the other way around though):

```
// this is a general loop
for ( init(); loopCondition(); step() )
    body();

// this is the general recursion of such a loop
function rec(recursionCondition, body, step) {
    if(recursionCondition()) {
        body();
        step();
        rec(recursionCondition, body, step);
    }
}
// and don't forget to initialise at the calling level:
init();
rec(loopCondition, body, step);
```

for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    doStuffOn(i);

function doStuffRec(int i, int length) {
    if(i < length) { // recursionCondition
        doStuffOn(i); // body
        int nextI = i + 1; // step
        doStuffRec(nextI, length);
    }
}
// calling level (initialisation of i)
doStuffRec(0, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can write every method that somehow loops in either a recursive or iterative way. You just need a condition to stop the loop.

Sometimes a method is easier to implement recursive than iterative. But a thing that should be noted is runtime.

```
long fibonacci(long Parameter) {
  if(Parameter <=1)
    return 1;
  else
    return fibonacci(Parameter-1)+fibonacci(Parameter-2);
}
```

Now try to find this for `n=40`, it will take pretty long. Why? Because the run-time-complexity is exponential. Means it takes exponentially longer to compute.

Compare this to a iterativ implementation:

```
long fibonacciIterativ(long Parameter) {
  int a=1, b=1;
  for(int i=1; i<Parameter;i++) {
    a = a+b;
    b = a-b;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Here the run-time-complexity is linear, means the runtime grows linearly with the input. (IIRC there was even a solution with a formula so the runtime is O(1), almost instant).

So for some things a recursive function feels more natural to write than an iterativ, sometimes the other way around. But by using a recursive function you have to be careful about the runtime!

Comment: I will note your runtime statement. I have done a problem to get the 5000th fib. number in Java. However the runtime was so large, it was impractical to get within 5 second requirement. Thank you.

Comment: for computer scientists fibonacci starts with 0 1 1 2 ... ;-)